# Enthought Canopy not working on Fedora. Giving error related to Zlib not found

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, fedora, canopy

I installed canopy from the .sh file provided from the link of the Enthought canopy site and then ran the following command after cd into the Canopy directory.

```
Ashish@LoneWarrior Canopy]$ ./canopy
Subprocess output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/Ashish/Canopy/appdata/canopy-2.1.3.3542.rh6-x86_64    /lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/gui.py", line 20, in <module>
from .toolkit import toolkit_object
  File "/home/Ashish/Canopy/appdata/canopy-2.1.3.3542.rh6-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/toolkit.py", line 99, in <module>
_init_toolkit()
  File "/home/Ashish/Canopy/appdata/canopy-2.1.3.3542.rh6-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/toolkit.py", line 65, in _init_toolkit
    be = import_toolkit(ETSConfig.toolkit)
  File "/home/Ashish/Canopy/appdata/canopy-2.1.3.3542.rh6-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/toolkit.py", line 58, in import_toolkit
    __import__(be + 'init')
  File "/home/Ashish/Canopy/appdata/canopy-2.1.3.3542.rh6-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/ui/qt4/init.py", line 18, in <module>
from pyface.qt import QtCore, QtGui, qt_api
  File "/home/Ashish/Canopy/appdata/canopy-2.1.3.3542.rh6-x86_64/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/qt/QtGui.py", line 8, in <module>
from PySide.QtGui import *
```

This is the main error : ZLIB_1.2.9 not found.

```
ImportError: /home/Ashish/Canopy/appdata/canopy-2.1.3.3542.rh6-x86_64/bin/../lib/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /lib64/libpng16.so.16)
```

I have tried changing the python default to 3 but still it is not working.

Comment: difficult to understand ..can you please add more info

Comment: I was trying to install Enthought Canopy. (https://store.enthought.com/downloads/) the python 3.5 version listed on this link. Now it was installed properly, but when i am trying to run it, it is giving this error :

ImportError: /home/Ashish/Canopy/appdata/canopy-2.1.3.3542.rh6-x86_64/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/../../libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /lib64/libpng16.so.16)

Comment: This is unreadable. Please format the traceback as a code block then comment back here when you have done so. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Hi Jonathan , I updated the traceback as code block.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the problem is on an Arch-based distribution. The *temporary* solution in this case is to downgrade `libpng` to 1.6.28 (this worked in my case). If you don't have it in your cache (`/var/cache/pacman/pkg'), you can download it from https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/libpng/

Then, following https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/downgrading_packages run in the directory with the downloaded file

```
# pacman -U libpng-1.6.28-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

(with the correct architecture, of course)

Don't forget to list `libpng` in `/etc/pacman.conf` among ignored packages to prevent upgrading. Look for the `[options]` section and add `IgnorePkg = libpng`.

**Improtant**. Keep in mind that downgrading packages is not harmless, therefore, this is only a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the libz file in the canopy environment is not compatible with the ZLIB installed in your system. 
For a quick fix: just copy the libz.so.1 file from lib directory to your canopy environment.
In my case it was

```
$ cp /usr/lib/libz.so.1 path-to-Canopy-install-directory/appdata/canopy-2.1.6.3665.rh6-x86_64/lib/libz.so.1
```